# PHP, Openwall Portable PHP password hashing framework returning different hashes for the same word

Tags: php, passwords, hash

When using

```
    $t_hash = new PasswordHash(12, FALSE);
```

each instance of

```
    $passHASH = $t_hash->HashPassword($password);
```

returns a different result even if the same word is presented. For example:

```
$t_hash->HashPassword('test') => $2a$12$7OKS2iaFMWfTYL7sHdl9EunA90.ZdiEIXgPcpXFsqrhD3z7tk06eO
$t_hash->HashPassword('test') => $2a$12$MWtkeSMQgUU22nCjRZmV8uG8dgHByM1nvyrk7XE9bw6znK8ZDFfwy
$t_hash->HashPassword('test') => $2a$12$Dx1sYTWIZmiREyn0KYh4G.daUNsmksYiSpnUKdaHZMrELIwmlhPyW
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue? When executing the following code

```
$t_hash = new PasswordHash(12, FALSE);
$passwordHASH = $t_hash->HashPassword($array['pass']);
$passwordHASH = $t_hash->HashPassword($passwordHASH,$array['pass']);
print($passwordHASH."<br/>");
$passwordHASH = $t_hash->HashPassword($passwordHASH,$array['pass']);
print($passwordHASH."<br/>");
$passwordHASH = $t_hash->HashPassword($passwordHASH,$array['pass']);
print($passwordHASH."<br/>");
$passwordHASH = $t_hash->HashPassword($passwordHASH,$array['pass']);
print($passwordHASH);
```

Returns

```
$2a$12$h3BLa3ytEmASpHgqVnmj4.3K5TwPPqwQG/cGHx/64KN1lqMtFZ8dC
$2a$12$x4uK46uBjv5xVstc4sR7iOrOJGPbSbWJRZIFlz9ir7ktydpYqStxO
$2a$12$r.CAy.amcVTFG.CtkTNg0eBN4HXP8tp4Yj/tsIVH7SxmK1bGjQJLS
$2a$12$8NzPVId7ReZVJJA7oWtkvuR2WKwPIUkpY/NQ2lszSH6EwdubzyIrm
```

Comment: Without knowing the implementation: is after `$hash = $t_hash->HashPassword($password);`  the output of `$t_hash->HashPassword($password,$hash);` consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is right behavior, `HashPassword` will use a random salt every time you call it, so the result won't be same.

Comment: How can I get this to return the same value?

Comment: @BrookJulias Why do you want get the same value? Don't use random salt will make security level down.

Comment: I am trying to match passwords, and am not able to. I am probably doing something wrong, but I cannot seem to figure out what.

Comment: @BrookJulias Try to find a method like `public function CheckPassword($password, $stored_hash)` to check the password.